# How to organize RMI Client-Server architecture

Tags: java, rmi

I am developing a secured Banking service in RMI with a GUI both for Server and Client.

The Server must be able to log every operations (new User, deleted User, Withdrawal, Lodgement...)
The Client will do these operations. 
As everything is secured, the Client must at first, create an account with a name and a password in the GUI. After that, the GUI adds the User in the Bank UserList(arrayList) as a new Customer and the User can do several operations. 
It seems straightforward at first but I think my conception is not correct.

Is it correct to send the whole Bank by RMI ? Because at first I thought Bank would be the server but I cannot find another way to do that. 
Currently, the Client GUI asks for a login and a password, and receives the Bank by RMI. A User is characterized by a name and a hash of the password.

```
private String name;
private byte[] passwordDigest;
```

In fact the GUI is doing every security checking and I don't know if it's relevant. When you type login//password, it will search the login in the Bank and compare the hash of the password. 
In fact I have the impression that the Client knows too much information because when you have the Bank you have everything..

Does it seem correct or do I need to change my implementation ?

Comment: does your Bank interface implement Serializable or Remote?

Comment: If you are actually developing a "real" banking service and not a test project or assignment or something, please, for the love of all that is holy, don't use RMI... I love Java but being able to use the interface from another language is useful :)

Comment: assignment or something <- this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two remote object classes.

The first one is obtained via `Naming.lookup()`; it is a singleton; and it contains a `login()` method.

This method returns the second remote object, which is not a singleton, not registered in the Registry, and is created anew for every return value. This object contains all the banking methods and also a `logout()` method, which unexports it; it probably also implements the `Unreferenced` interface so it can detect a dead client, and unexport itself. Because it exists once per client, it can hold client state, and because it can only be obtained by a successful login step it solves your security problem.

```
public interface Login extends Remote
{
    Session login(String username, char[] password /* or whatever */)
        throws LoginException, RemoteException;
}

public interface Session extends Remote
{
    void logout() throws RemoteException;
    void deposit(...) throws RemoteException;
    void withdraw(...) throws RemoteException;
}

public class LoginImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Login
{
    public Session login(String username, char[] password)
        throws LoginException, RemoteException
    {
        // username/password check; if it fails throw a LoginException
        return new SessionImpl(username); // or whatever
    }
}

public class SessionImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Session, Unreferenced
{
    public void logout() throws RemoteException
    {
        unexportObject(this, true);
    }

    public void unreferenced()
    {
        unexportObject(this, true); // needs to be in a try/catch block of course
    }

    // etc
}
```

I described this as the Remote Session pattern in my book in 2001.

Of course you *also* need transport layer security: see `javax.rmi.ssl.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't understand where the Bank is in all of this. Session is doing everything that Bank is supposed to do ? Because in my implementation, Bank contains a list of Customer and each customer have a list of Account.

Comment: @xenom That architecture doesn't make sense. Any given customer should only be able to operate his own accounts. I don't see where Bank comes into it at all.

Comment: Yeah I'm changing everything right know.. Everything will stay on Server side and only the two remote object you gave me will go through RMI.

Comment: Hmm another precision. Now that everything operation is called in Session. Can I pass the Bank instance in the Session constructor ? Because deposit/withdraw are really implemented in Bank.
For example the constructor would be `SessionImpl(String login,Bank bank)` and for example withdraw would do 
`this.bank.withdraw(login,amount)`
Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how Remote interfaces work.  the client does not *have* the Bank, it only has a reference to a *remote* instance of a Bank.  all the method calls made by the client on the Bank interface are actually turned into *remote* calls against the *remote* instance of the Bank (running in the server).

presumably, the security checking is done *inside* the Bank methods *on every method call*.

Comment: So there is no problem concerning the Bank reference.

Concerning the security checking. As I said Bank have a list of User and User has a name and the hash of the password given in the constructor.
When typing login/password in the GUI, you mean it's preferable to have every method of Bank asking the password attribute ? And doing the checking itself and not the GUI ?

Comment: @xenom - if you truly want your banking app to be secure, every call has to be authenticated.  this can be via checking creds everytime, or through some secure token exchange (where the token is provided on each call).  checking the creds once and then making a bunch of calls is _not_ secure.