# JAVA RMI client specific variable

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to store some client specific variable in a RMI implementation.

Interface:

```
    public interface RMIInterface extends Remote{
    public void setName(String name) throws RemoteException;
    public String getMessage() throws RemoteException; 
}
```

Implementation:

```
    public class TSImp implements RMIInterface {
    private String name;
    @Override
    public String getMessage() throws RemoteException {
        return "Hello "+this.name;
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) throws RemoteException {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Server:

```
try {
    RMIInterface i = new TSImp();
    RMIInterface stub = (RMIInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(i, 1099);
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    registry.rebind("TrafficServer", i);
    System.out.println("Server started");
} catch (RemoteException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Client:

```
        try {
        Registry registry=LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1099);
        RMIInterface rmi = (RMIInterface) registry.lookup("TrafficServer");
        rmi.setName("Alice");
        System.out.println(rmi.getMessage());
    } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Now if I try to run multiple clients by passing different parameters in the setName function, it seems to replace the variable in my server.

Example:

```
Client1:
       setName("Alice")
Client2:
       setName("Bob")
Client1:
       getMessage() //returns "Bob"
```

Is there a way to have client/connection specific variables?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Remote Session pattern. The remote object bound in the Registry is a singleton, which should have something like a login() method, which returns a unique per-client instance of a second remote interface, called something like RemoteSession, which contains the real API used by clients, and whose implementation can contain per-client information, as there is an instance per client. This second interface can contain a logout() method, which unexports the remote object,and/or its implementation can implement Unreferenced, which also unexports itself.

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632442/how-to-organize-rmi-client-server-architecture ?

Comment: Something exactly like [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635838/207421) there.

Comment: I tried to implement according to your Login/Session method. It works but how do I make SessionImpl save some client specific info like 'username'? I tried using ThreadLocal in SessionImpl but as soon as LoginImpl returns the Session, it gets destroyed.

Comment: I haven't said anything about ThreadLocal except that it won't work. Don't do it. You don't need it. RemoteSession is all you need.

Comment: I am not using ThreadLocal, Suppose in your example you are calling the withdraw() function. How does the SessionImpl know from which back account to withdraw from? I am sure the client is not passing the Bank class. right? Or in my case how will it know if it is Alice or Bob?

Comment: The SessionImpl object is specific to the user. It's a session. It contains his name, login details, bank accounts etc. as data members, whatever you need. Of course if he has more than one account you will have to provide a parameter. I don't know why you mentioned ThreadLocal in your previous comment, if you're not using it.