# Java RMI: How to have different variables for each client?

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to understand the basics of RMI in Java but I am having difficulties in setting a variable for each client.
What I am trying to do is a calculator with a floating variable for memory, memory that is not shared between clients. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a solution.
For those trying to do something similar, look here [How to organize RMI Client-Server architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632442/how-to-organize-rmi-client-server-architecture/13635838#13635838)